# Real time notification from web server to client bowers

Tags: php, jquery, notifications, real-time

I am developing an appointments center web application using php+mysql. what I currently trying to do is to send notification when an appointment has been made from web server to client/user bowers without third party pushers and without using jQuery SetInterval AJAX request. I think SetInterval & AJAX is a bad approach because there would be too much traffic between the client and the server.

How can I implement notifications without polling the server with SetInterval?

Comment: You can read my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524727/how-to-output-in-realtime-when-number-is-change/16531635#16531635). I hope it helps. Oh and you won't need to have a node server or anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using NodeJs.
NodeJS is javascript on your server that pushes content to connected clients in real time.

Its really easy to use and setup.
You need a server dedicated to the real time app, I use http://nodejitsu.com.

Server Side

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
, url = require('url')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
// parse URL
var requestURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

// if there is a message, send it
if(requestURL.query.message)
    sendMessage(decodeURI(requestURL.query.message));

// end the response
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end("");
}

function sendMessage(message) {
io.sockets.emit('notification', {'message': message});
}
```

Client Side

```
<script src="socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
});
</script>
```

I added the easy to use example by @intivev below to complete the answer for future readers

Comment: @MDDY I am just at the beginning of this. Please help on this. From where i can get `socket.io.min.js` file? can you provide some more detail on given answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use WebSockets for this, the [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/) is a PHP implementation built on top of the [React library](http://reactphp.org/). I've used both these libraries in production applications and have been more than happy with them.

Yes, using node.js is an option and maybe a better one - dependant on your current situation.

Anthony.

Comment: when it comes to websocket, for sure node.js is better

Answer (score 2):

I feel u are choosing the wrong language for this purpose (PHP), there may be  a way out to do it in PHP , but i am damp sure that its would be a twisted one. I recommend using node.js for this purpose as using it you can accomplish pushing notifications to client in much simpler way

Server Side

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
, url = require('url')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
// parse URL
var requestURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

// if there is a message, send it
if(requestURL.query.message)
    sendMessage(decodeURI(requestURL.query.message));

// end the response
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end("");
}

function sendMessage(message) {
io.sockets.emit('notification', {'message': message});
}
```

Client Side

```
<script src="socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
});
</script>
```

So you see its lot eassy if you use the suitable language for it