# How to append sting array to html div ni ajax.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Here I have output with string array. Comes from php json. I want to give this output to html div tabcontent but I don't know how to do this. here is my little code any one can help me.

> [{"id":"1","p_name":"g_t1","P_Type":"gp_1","paid_type":"0"},{"id":"2","p_name":"g_t2","P_Type":"gp_2","paid_type":"1"},{"id":"3","p_name":"g_t3","P_Type":"gp_3","paid_type":"0"}]

```js
   $("a.tablinks").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var p_name = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(p_name);
    $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Gettabdata",
            type: "POST",           
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{Paper_name : p_name},

           success : function(data){                    

                if(data != ""){                 
                    data = JSON.stringify(data);                    
                    console.log(data);
                   alert(data);

                }else{                                  
                    data = JSON.stringify(data);
                    console.log(data);
                   $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                      alert(k + ':' + v+ " 1 working else .!"); 
                   });
                }
           },
           error : function(data){              
                data = JSON.stringify(data);    
                console.log(data);

                   $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                      alert(k + ':' + v + ' error'); 
                   });
           }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">

                            <div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">                            

                                <label style="padding:10px 10px;">  Label Name </label>
                                <span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>
                                </span>     
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

here is my ajax

```
<script>
   $("a.tablinks").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var p_name = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(p_name);
    $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Gettabdata",
            type: "POST",           
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{Paper_name : p_name},

           success : function(data){                    

                if(data != ""){                 
                    data = JSON.stringify(data);                    
                    console.log(data);
                   alert(data);

                }else{                                  
                    data = JSON.stringify(data);
                    console.log(data);
                   $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                      alert(k + ':' + v+ " 1 working else .!"); 
                   });
                }
           },
           error : function(data){              
                data = JSON.stringify(data);    
                console.log(data);

                   $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                      alert(k + ':' + v + ' error'); 
                   });
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to add retrieved string array to below  html div tabcontent (tabcontent input-group class will create three times. depends on number of id.).

```
<div id="id" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">

                            <div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">                            

                                <label style="padding:10px 10px;">  Label Name </label>
                                <span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>
                                </span>     
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

what to add in html tabcontent.?

Tabcontent id is `P_type`,
Lable is `p_name`,

Comment: What is the html element that is mapped with the JSON response. I mean where is 'p_name' from JSON displayed in HTML? Inside label? Inside span? where?

Comment: similar to [get variable from php file using jquery ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341434/get-variable-from-php-file-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: _sting array_........??

Comment: @AKA I make edit with details. Tabcontent id is P_type, Lable is p_name,

Comment: yes it is string array you can see above.@Jai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the div dynamically so create a function that will take this json array as parameter and loop over to it to create `div` dynamically with necessary `id` and `label`

First, you need to specify this function inside if block `data != ""`

```
if(data != ""){    
   createDiv(data);  //this function is responsible to create div dynamically      
   data = JSON.stringify(data);                    
   console.log(data);
   alert(data);
}
```

Now the `createDiv()` function goes like this

```
function createDiv(data){
var dynamicHTML = '';
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  dynamicHTML += '<div id="'+ data[i].P_Type +'" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">'+
                        '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                            '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">'+ data[i].p_name +'</label>'+
                            '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">'+
                                '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>'+
                            '</span>'+   
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
}
$("body").append(dynamicHTML);
```

}

The dynamically created div is appended right away in the HTML body. You can specify a parent `div` say, `<div id='content'></div>` and change this line of code inside the createDiv() function 
`$("body").append(dynamicHTML);` to `$("#content").append(dynamicHTML);` 
if you want to append it inside a `div` in the page.

Comment: This is perfect answer. but can you tell me How can I clear div data for new tab content.

Comment: You can simply use $("body").html(''); exactly before the for loop (or immediately after for before appending the dynamicHTML). This will clear out all the previous HTML of the tab content. As i mentioned, use your selector instead of $("body") within which you have this dynamic HTML.