# Opening a window in Javascript with the value of a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to open a window with a 5 second delay when a button is clicked. I'm trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sample() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.open('<?php echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()); ?>', '_self');
   }, 5000); 
}
</script>
```

which I call in the `onclick` attribute of the `<button>`:

```
<button class="ui right labeled icon button btn btn_secondary" onClick="sample();">
    <i class="copy icon"></i>
    <span><?php esc_html_e('Copy', 'wp-coupon'); ?></span>
</button>
```

The problem is that `<?php echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()); ?>` doesn't return the correct value, and correct URL doesn't open.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: pop up blockers will most likely block the window.

Comment: So what is the value written when the page loads, that is the value. View the page source. Issue would be with the PHP code.

Comment: This is mixture of JS and PHP; such a thing is not possible. You should try another approach.

Comment: Of course is such mixing possible, but it won't work as expected sometimes. In this case, you should explain which URL is opened and what you expect

Comment: Ok ill try to explain better:

Comment: <?php echo esc_attr( wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url() ); ?> returns out url value correctly. I have a button and i need when someone click it start a counter of 5 sec, and then out url loads.

Answer (score 1):

You need ajax to read that php variable asynchronously from javascript. Otherwise i think your question is better answered here:

[Get variable from PHP file using JQuery/AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341434/get-variable-from-php-file-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: No knowledge about that.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page address correct?

```
esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url())
```

For test your script in php file use construction:

```
<?php
   //php code
?>
<script>
function sample() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.open('<?php echo('https://google.com'); ?>', '_self');
   }, 5000);
}
</script>
<button class="ui right labeled icon button btn btn_secondary" onClick="sample();">test</button>
<?php
  //php code
?>
```

Comment: yes, if i echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()) it shows http://www.example.com/go-to-store/1198 so is correct, but with the function it shows another url  http://www.example.com/go-to-store/202.

Comment: Maybe use:  var url='<? echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()); ?>';   and : window.open(url, '_self');

Comment: think php problem because with google.com it works correctly